# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP/mySQL search script that for some reason, after the latest update by the developer, has stopped working when searching with wildcards (*). What's worse, it not only stopped working, but it returns the following nasty (for visitors) mySQL error, which is based on a *donut* wildcard search:

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.category_id FROM products a
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid=a.ownerid
WHERE a.active=1 AND a.approved=1 AND a.deleted=0 AND a.creation_in_progress=0
AND a.name LIKE '%%' 
AND ((a.name REGEXP '( )*(*donut*)( )*') OR (a.description REGEXP '( )*(*donut*)( )*'))
```

The error:

```
Mysql Error: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

Unfortunately, the developer can't (or won't) fix it and it's rendering my website useless if someone does a wildcard search.

Any ideas what the problem could be? Or an easy fix? I already tried putting a backslash before the $keywords_search but that didn't work. I also tried running the above mySQL query directly in PhpMyAdmin and it produced the same error.

I also tried to completely get rid of the REGEXP part but then it won't return any results at all.

The PHP search code of this part is as follows:

```
$query[] = "((a.name REGEXP '( )*(" . str_replace(' ', ')*( )*(', $keywords_search) . ")( )*') 
OR (a.description REGEXP '( )*(" . str_replace(' ', ')*( )*(', $keywords_search) . ")( )*'))";
```

Comment: See, this is why [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) was made.

Comment: Shouldn't the `( )*` blocks be `( *)`? I'm pretty sure you can't apply repetition operators `*+` to capture groups `( )` which seems to tally with the error message... (and before some smart alec says it, yes obviously you can apply them *inside* capture groups, but that wasn't the point I was making and well you know it ;-) )

Comment: This fixed it for me:

$keywords_search = str_replace("*", ".*", $keywords_search);

Comment: Seems like somehow my code got stripped out. The replacement is wildcard for dotwildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to escape your stars (`*`) if you want it to match a literal star. If you want it to translate "any string", you need to change it to `.*`. It's that simple. Just take the user's input and apply the replacing on it before you query the database.

Comment: I read your answer about 10 times and finally came up with the following code. And guess what? It WORKED! Thank you so much. Here's the code if anyone is wondering, I hope it's correct but it works for me -> $keywords_search = str_replace("*", ".*", $keywords_search);

Comment: Seems like somehow my code got stripped out. The replacement is wildcard for dotwildcard.

Comment: Edit your comment, to add code surround it with ticks like inline code in a post: ` `like so` `